# How to set chart type "setChartType" by script to org chart. I found BAR<LINE, etc... but not ORG chart

Tags: google-apps-script

How to set chart type "`setChartType`" by script to `org chart`.
I found `BAR<LINE, etc... but not ORG chart!`

This is the code I try

```
var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart();
   chartBuilder.addRange(range)
       .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
       .setOption('title', 'My Line Chart!')
       .setPosition(2,2,0,0)

   sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
```

Line 3 doesn't support

```
.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.ORG)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the documentation for [setChartType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#setChartType(ChartType)) and follow the link to the documentation page for the argument type, [ChartType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-type), where you'll clearly see that `ORG` is simply not a supported chart type.